# Can we loop over all the constants defined in a module in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a map of all the status-codes constants defined [here](https://docs.rs/http/latest/http/status/struct.StatusCode.html). Something like this

```
{ 
StatusCode::OK : 0,
StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST : 0,
...
}
```

These constants are defined as pub const in that module, so i was wondering if its possible to iterate over all pub contants in a module and intialize this map.

Is it possible?

I tried googling but could not find anything of help.

Comment: You can only do it by hand (or at most with a macro, but then you still have to write all constants explicitly).

Comment: But what that map should be anyway? Do you want to map from "status code" to it's numerical value? That's what those constants do by themselves.

Comment: I agree, I feel like this is an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to achieve? To answer your original question, no, it isn't possible. There's no way of iterating over an API itself like in Python, and there never will be, because in Rust, compile time and run time are decoupled. In Python, those two kind of merge and are dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible.

This is something that would need to be explicitly added to the http crate, but it hasn't been added because this is not a common need for implementers of the HTTP protocol. The list is not exhaustive (e.g. there's no [425 Too Early](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/425), plus a server may produce privately used status codes), and this is not a list of status codes that you'd need for any specific purpose.

If you want a list of status codes, make that list yourself. This has the advantage of not unexpectedly changing if http adds some new codes in a minor version.

Comment: For now i only have a subset of statuscodes to be used, so will create my own list. Thanks.